# Sync mail with MS Exchange

Tags: email, synchronization, exchange-server

Does anyone on here have experience with Microsoft Exchange?

I have a PC, MAC, iPhone and iPad. I have an account for work and 2 personal accounts.

Will using MS Exchange allow me to sync everything between all devices?

Can I sync existing email if I open an MS Exchange account?

I tried to find this information online but was hard than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can sync all your mail, contacts and calendars across your devices with Exchange. iPhones and iPads (and Android devices too) support ActiveSync (which is the Microsoft technology that enables mobile syncing).

When you create an Exchange account existing emails won't automatically be transferred into it (ie anything already in your mail app won't move automatically into the Exchange account). Instead you'll need to migrate the messages across. Some providers offer services to do this for you, or you can manually do it by exporting and important mailboxes in your email app.

Answer (score 1):

yes, I myself is using three different devices to access the emails, contacts,calendar through microsoft exchange.

Also refernce is available at  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1151.exchange-activesync-overview.aspx

Comment: do you have more than one email account set up? I have my personal one and my work one set up in the Exchange trial, and it's mostly working well. However, on my Mac I can't choose a "from' address where as on Windows I can (Using Outlook 2011 for Mac). Any ideas? Also there is no option on my iPhone to choose which account to send mail from, I don't want it to come from my .onmicrosoft account. Any ideas?